# Enviar imagens para diferentes pastas e gravar cada uma em um tabela do banco de dados usando php

Tags: php, mysql, formulário, upload

Sou iniciante em php e estou tentado criar um site.Como faço para enviar 6 imagens ao mesmo tempo pelo formulário, fazer com que cada  uma seja enviada para a pasta especifica e gravar no banco de dados.
Nome das tabelas no banco de dados:

`nomedarom`
 `imagem_da_rom1`
 `imagem_da_rom2`
 `imagem_da_rom3`
 `imagem_da_rom4`
 `imagem_da_rom5`

Nome das pastas para enviar cada imagem:

`logodarom`
`imagens1`
`imagens2`
`imagens3`
`inagens4`
`imagens5`

Arquivo php:

```
<?php
    include_once 'conexao.php';
    include_once 'functions.php';

    if(isset($_POST['cadastrar'])):

        $marca_do_aparelho   = $_POST['marca_do_aparelho'];
        $modelo  = $_POST['modelo'];
        $nome_da_rom  = $_POST['nome_da_rom'];
        $descricao_da_rom  = $_POST['descricao_da_rom'];
        $download  = $_POST['download'];
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
        $data = date('Y-m-d H:i');
        cadastrarComPdo2( $marca_do_aparelho , $modelo,  $nome_da_rom,  $descricao_da_rom,  $download, $data);
        echo "cadastrado com sucesso";
   endif;

   ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <title>Formularios</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form  action="" method="post">
         <p> 
            <label for="marca_do_aparelho"> Nome marca do aparelho</label>
            <input type="text" name="marca_do_aparelho" />
         </p>
         <p>
         <p> 
            <label for="modelo">Modelo do aparelho</label>
            <input type="text" name="modelo" />
         </p>
         <p>
            <label for="nome_da_rom">Nome da custom rom</label>
            <input type="text" name="nome_da_rom" />
         </p>
         <p>
            <label>descreva a custom rom</label>
            <textarea name= "descricao_da_rom"></textarea>
         </p>
         <p> 
            <label for="download">Aqui o linkin para download</label>
            <input type="text" name="download" />
         </p>
         <p>
            <label for="logo_da_rom">Logo da rom:</label>
            <input type="file" name="logo_da_rom"
         </p>
         <p>
            <label for="imagem_da_rom1">Primeira imagem da rom:</label>
            <input type="file" name="imagem_da_rom1"
         </p>
         <p>
            <label for="imagem_da_rom2">Segunda imagem da rom:</label>
            <input type="file" name="imagem_da_rom2"
         </p>
         <p>
            <label for="imagem_da_rom3">Terceira imagem da rom:</label>
            <input type="file" name="imagem_da_rom3"
         </p>
         <p>
            <label for="imagem_da_rom4">Quarta imagem da rom:</label>
            <input type="file" name="imagem_da_rom4"
         </p>
         <p>
            <label for="imagem_da_rom5">Quinta imagem da rom:</label>
            <input type="file" name="imagem_da_rom5"
         </p>
         <p>
            <label for="submit"></label>
            <input type="submit" name="cadastrar" value="vai" />
         </p>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Segundo arquivo php:

```
       try{
           $pdo = conectarComPdo();
           $pdo-> beginTransaction();

           $cadastrar = $pdo ->prepare("INSERT  INTO roms(marca_do_aparelho, modelo, nome_da_rom, descricao_da_rom, download, data)VALUES(:marca_do_aparelho, :modelo, :nome_da_rom, :descricao_da_rom, :download, :data)");
           $cadastrar -> bindValue("marca_do_aparelho", $marca_do_aparelho);
           $cadastrar -> bindValue(":modelo", $modelo);
           $cadastrar -> bindValue(":nome_da_rom", $nome_da_rom);
           $cadastrar -> bindValue(":descricao_da_rom", $descricao_da_rom);
           $cadastrar -> bindValue("download", $download);
           $cadastrar -> bindValue("data", $data);
           $cadastrar -> execute();


           if($cadastrar -> rowCount()== 1):

               echo "cadastrado com sucesso";
           else:

               echo"erro";

           endif;
           $pdo->commit();
       }catch(PDOExcepetion $e){
           echo "erro: ".$e ->getMessage();
           $pdo->rollBack();
       }

   } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro você precisa alterar essa tag:

```
<form  action="" method="post">
```

Para:

```
<form  action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Depois você precisa resgatar essas imagens e move-las para a pasta:

```
        /* 
        eu verifico arquivo por arquivo se eles estão vazios, 
        se não estiverem vazios, movo para a pasta correta
        */

    if(!empty($_FILES['logo_da_rom']))
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['logo_da_rom']['tmp_name'], "nomedarom/".$_FILES['logo_da_rom']['name']);

    if(!empty($_FILES['imagem_da_rom1']))
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagem_da_rom1']['tmp_name'], "imagens1/".$_FILES['imagem_da_rom1']['name']);

    if(!empty($_FILES['imagem_da_rom2']))
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagem_da_rom2']['tmp_name'], "imagens2/".$_FILES['imagem_da_rom2']['name']);

    if(!empty($_FILES['imagem_da_rom3']))
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagem_da_rom3']['tmp_name'], "imagens3/".$_FILES['imagem_da_rom3']['name']);

    if(!empty($_FILES['imagem_da_rom1']))
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagem_da_rom4']['tmp_name'], "imagens4/".$_FILES['imagem_da_rom4']['name']);

    if(!empty($_FILES['imagem_da_rom1']))
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagem_da_rom5']['tmp_name'], "imagens5/".$_FILES['imagem_da_rom5']['name']);
```

*obs.: Existe um modo mais fácil de recuperar essas imagens com switch por exemplo. Fiz dessa forma pra você ter um exemplo didático.*

Quando se trata de arquivos algumas considerações são válidas:

- O nome do arquivo pode ser repetido?
- Quais extensões são válidas?
- Existe um tamanho máximo para cada arquivo?

É importante que você trate essas e outras informações para que seu sistema não tenha erros ou bugs.

Para cadastrar no banco não tem segredo, é a mesma forma que você cadastrou os outros valores na outra tabela, você pode usar o mesmo PDO que você instanciou inclusive:

```
...

$img1 = $_FILES['imagem_da_rom1']['name'];
$img2 = $_FILES['imagem_da_rom2']['name'];
$img3 = $_FILES['imagem_da_rom3']['name'];
$img4 = $_FILES['imagem_da_rom4']['name'];
$img5 = $_FILES['imagem_da_rom5']['name'];


$cadastrarImagem = $pdo ->prepare("INSERT  INTO tabelaImagens(imagem_da_rom1 , imagem_da_rom2, imagem_da_rom3, imagem_da_rom4, imagem_da_rom5   )VALUES(:imagem1, :imagem2, :imagem3, :imagem4, :imagem5)");
           $cadastrarImagem -> bindValue("imagem1", $img1);
  ...

           $cadastrarImagem -> execute();
```

Espero que te ajude. Abraço!